# Delete a set of data from .csv file after figuring out the duplicate values

Tags: r, filtering

The problem is I have a set of data in two columns. Ex:

A B

3 5

6 **7**

**4 4**

7 8

1 6

8 **7**

Here I want to figure out the values that are same in both A & B column(4 & 4). Also I want to know the duplicates that are present in the B column(7 & 7).

After figuring it out, is there a way to remove them and keep in a different file?

Also if you can guide me to a good data manipulation with R content.

Answer (score 0):

We create two indexes for two columns

```
i1 <- df1$A == df1$B
i2 <- with(df1, duplicated(B)|duplicated(B, fromLast = TRUE))
df1[i1,1]
#[1] 4

df1[i1|i2,2]
#[1] 7 4 7
```

---

As the number of elements to be removed are different for both columns, we loop through the columns and remove those values based on the logical index

```
Map(`[`, df1, list(!i1, !(i1|i2)))
#$A
#[1] 3 6 7 1 8

#$B
#[1] 5 8 6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(3L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 8L), B = c(5L, 7L, 4L, 
 8L, 6L, 7L)), .Names = c("A", "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe

```
db<-data.frame(A=c(3,6,4,7,1,8),
                B=c(5,7,4,8,6,7))
```

Identify equal and duplicated data

```
not_equal<-!db[,1]==db[,2]
not_duplicated<-!duplicated(db[,2])
```

Filter out

```
db[not_equal & not_duplicated,]
  A B
1 3 5
2 6 7
4 7 8
5 1 6
```